# How do you make cache folder content deleteable?

Tags: android, caching, sd-card

Okay so I've noticed that even though I use the correct path for the cache folder Android doesn't register the content in the folder so the user can't delete the cache content by going into settings -> programs -> administrate -> select program -> clear cache. The folder is deleted properly on uninstal but not if the user actively try to clear the cache. This is not a major issue but its still a minor problem because the user don't get a proper idea of how much space the application uses at the SD card.
Is there anything I as developer can do to update these values or am I doing something wrong somewhere else?

Comment: Are you using `getDownloadCacheDirectory()`?

Comment: Nope. I save my files in their designated android/data/packagename/cache folder

Comment: So you are using Context's `getCacheDir()` or hardcoding the path?

Comment: hardcoding, but I've noticed this seems to be a problem for other apps aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Saving cache files
>
> If you'd like to cache some data, rather than store it persistently,
>   you should use getCacheDir() to open a File that represents the
>   internal directory where your application should save temporary cache
>   files.
>
> When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete
>   these cache files to recover space. However, you should not rely on
>   the system to clean up these files for you. You should always maintain
>   the cache files yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space
>   consumed, such as 1MB. When the user uninstalls your application,
>   these files are removed.

I guess you should handle the removal of yourself. If you want to remove the content if the user cleans the app data create a `sharedPreference` and clean the cache when the app starts and that preference is not defined.

Comment: Well I use the external storage, that might be why it isn't added as "cache". To refrase, external storage cache folder doesn't count as cache in program manager?

Comment: @Warpzit: Honestly, I am not sure :(

Comment: I'll leave the question open until I get a definite answer then :)

Comment: @Warpzit: Sure! Sorry about that.